# importing a file with d3 script in it

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I made an HTML file in the  tags i put a lot of code including d3. I tried to move it to a separate file by copying and pasting it. The code works, if i run it in the console or have it all in the one file, it works.
The file i'm importing is called graph this is how: `<link rel="import" href="graph.html">` 
I tried opening the file with python -m SimpleHTTPServer but that doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: How are you including d3? It could be that d3 still isn't fully loaded by the time your script executes.

Comment: <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>